# property inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties

```
Public class ClassB : ClassA
{
}

public class GeneralClass
{
   public ClassA test
   {
      get{}
      set{}
   }
}
public class specificClass :GeneralClass
{
   public ClassB test
   {
      get{}
      set{}
   }
}
```

As you can see the property test is inherited in specificClass from generalClass but here I want to change the type to ClassB (`ClassB:ClassA`) . can I do something like this so anytime I'm using the `specializedClass.test` I don't need to typecast it to classB ?

edit 1 : I forgot to mention that now it's giving me the warning that **test hide inherited member test .use new keyword if hiding is intended .**

Comment: I would suggest cleaning up your example, as it doesn't make any sense at the moment.  I'm not sure what your goal is because of that

Comment: I assume that `specificClass` should inherit `GeneralClass`, this is not the case in your example!

Comment: Also you have mixed up the type and the name in your property definitions. It should be `public ClassA test { get; set; }`

Comment: @Vinz sorry you're right .I correct them. thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't modify the return type as you override methods and properties. C# doesn't support [return type covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type).

By the way, if you don't need to override the property and just want to return the base value casted to some specific type, you can declare a *[`new` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922550/new-modifier-in-c)* to hide the base class one. Note that it's not return type covariance. It's just a distinct property that happens to have an identical name:

```
public new ClassB test {
     get { return base.test as ClassB; }
     set { base.test = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When overridding methods and properties, you have to use the exact same types as the base method/property, even when it may be safe to use a subclass. You can hide properties using the `new` keyword, but it won't be virtually dispatched when it is called on the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Mehrdad Afshari just updated his question to reflect what I was about to write.  Basically, what you're looking for is:

```
    public class ClassA
    {

    }

    public class ClassB : ClassA
    {

    }

    public class GeneralClass
    {
        public ClassA myClass { get; set; }
    }

    public class SpecificClass : GeneralClass
    {
        new public ClassB myClass { get; set; }
    }

    public myFunction()
    {

        var sc = new SpecificClass();

        sc.myClass = new ClassB();

        Console.WriteLine("sc.GetType() = " + sc.myClass.GetType());

        var gc = (GeneralClass)sc;

        gc.myClass = new ClassA();

        Console.WriteLine("gc.GetType() = " + gc.myClass.GetType());

        Console.WriteLine("sc.GetType() = " + sc.myClass.GetType());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact problem you can solve it with generics. (But it's kind of complicated)

Note: `GeneralClass : AbstractGeneralClass` and `SpecificClass : AbstractGeneralClass`

You can:

- store instances of `GeneralClass` and `SpecificClass` in `AbstractGeneralClass`
- access `testAsClassA` if you have a variable of type `AbstractGeneralClass`
- access `ClassB test` if you have a variable of type `SpecificClass`

```
 class ClassA { }
    class ClassB : ClassA { }

    abstract class AbstractGeneralClass
    {
        /* functionality that does not depend on test */

        public abstract ClassA testAsClassA { get; }
    }

    abstract class AbstractGeneralClass : AbstractGeneralClass where T : ClassA
    {
        T myProperty;
        public T test
        {
            get { return myProperty; }
            set { myProperty = value; }
        }

        public override ClassA testAsClassA { get { return myProperty; } }
    }

    class GeneralClass : AbstractGeneralClass { }

    class SpecificClass : AbstractGeneralClass { }
```